# Getting segmentation fault when using fgets and strtok

Tags: c

I am trying to read a txt file and then split the numbers and store them in a matrix. However when I try to use strtok I'm getting segmentation fault. Can somebody help me with this please！

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void parse(char*file1)
{
  FILE *fp;
  char str[60];
  char str1[60];

  fp = fopen(file1, "r");
  int row;
  int col;
  fgets(str, 60, fp);
  row=atof(str);
  fgets(str, 60, fp);
  col=atof(str);
  double *matrix;
  matrix = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*row*col);    

  int j;
  int i;
  for(i=0; i < row; i++) {
      for(j=0; j < col; j++) {
        matrix[i*col +j] = 1;
      }
   }

  for(i=0; i < row; i++) {
      for(j=0; j < col; j++) {
          printf("%f ",matrix[i*col +j]);
      }
    printf("\n");
   }
  printf("**************************");

  double dtoken;
  while (!feof(fp))
  {
    if (fgets(str, 60, fp)==NULL)
    {
      break;
    }
    else
    {    
      char*token;
      token = strtok(str, " ");
      while (token!=NULL)
      {
      printf("%s ",token);
      token=strtok(NULL, " ");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

   fclose(fp);


  }

  int main(int argc, char*argv[])
  {
  int i;
  char*file1;
  char*file2;
  if (argc==1)    //print error when no txt file is entered
  {
    printf("Invalid text file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  else if (argc==2)
  {
    file1=argv[1];
    file2=argv[1];
  }
  else if (argc==3)
  {
    file1=argv[1];
    file2=argv[2];
  }
  else
  {
    exit(1);//more than 3 files, invalid
  }
  //
  parse(file1);

  }
```

I tried copying str to str1 and use strtok on str1 and that did not work either.

Comment: 1. `str1[60]='\0';`  should be `str1[59]='\0';`. You need to count from `0 to 59`

Comment: Try to indent your code as it would be easy on eyes.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `parse()` change `str1[60]='\0';` to `str1[59]='\0';`

As you have allocated memory only for `60` characters and trying to access the `61st` character.

In arrays you need to count from `0 to 59` and not from `1 to 60` if the size of allocated array is `60`.

**EDIT: 
Check for the return value of `fopen`**

After `fp = fopen(file1, "r");` add below code

```
if (fp == NULL ) {
    printf("Error: Unable to open file\n");
    return ;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but that is not the reason y I'm getting the error.

Comment: That's not the problem with it. the opening the file is no problem. I can print out str with the correct value, but when I try to tokenize the string it gives me error

Answer (score 1):

You are causing undefined behavior by accessing `str1` out of bounds. You can replace the lines:

```
strncpy(str1,str,60);
str1[60]='\0';
```

by

```
strcpy(str1,str);
```

That will work fine since both `str` and `str1` are arrays with 60 elements.

Comment: If I delete everything about str1 the same problem still occurs

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "delete everything about `str1`".

Comment: I changed the code above. I basically deleted copying str to str1.